# Checking if a macro expands to one of two given strings

Tags: conditionals

I want to test if the expansion of a given macro, say `\mystring`, is equal to one of two given strings, say `string1`, `string2`. I guess it's possible to do this with **etoolbox**, with something like:

```
\ifstrequal{\mystring}{string2 or string3}{code for True}{code for False}
```

How? Or, is there another possible method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\def\mytest#1{%
  \def\tempa{string1}%
  \def\tempb{string2}%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifdefstrequal{#1}{\tempa}} or 
              test {\ifdefstrequal{#1}{\tempb}}}
  {True}
  {False}%
}

\mytest\relax % <- False
\def\xyz{string1}
\mytest\xyz % <- True
\def\xyz{string2}
\mytest\xyz % <- True
\def\xyz{string3}
\mytest\xyz % <- False
```

### EDIT

A shorter implementation with expl3:

```
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \mytest #1
  {
   \bool_if:nTF
     { \str_if_eq_p:no { string1 } { #1 } || \str_if_eq_p:no { string2 } { #1 } }
     {True}
     {False}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

This has some advantages over the solution with `etoolbox`: it's more easily extendable to do other checks and doesn't require defining temporary control sequences for storing the strings to check. But the main advantage is that this `\mytest` is expandable, while the one with `etoolbox` isn't.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not stuck on using `etoolbox`, you could use `IfStrEqCase` from [the `xstring` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xstring/). This has the added benefit that in case where you want to allow for numerical equivalency (ie., "0.5" matches ".50") you can use identical syntax with `IfEqCase`.

Using these macros directly allows you to specify different code to be executed depending on which string was matched. If you just want to execute a particular piece of code for the case where thse is a match I have defined the `\StrEqEither` macro for you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}
This tests for string matches (i.e., $+3$ not equal $3$):\par
\smallskip
\IfStrEqCase{a}{{a}{matched case 1}{b}{matched case 2}}[matched none]\par
\IfStrEqCase{b}{{a}{matched case 1}{b}{matched case 2}}[matched none]\par
\IfStrEqCase{c}{{a}{matched case 1}{b}{matched case 2}}[matched none]\par
\IfStrEqCase{+3}{{3}{matched case 1}{5}{matched case 2}}[matched none]\par
\IfStrEqCase{0.5}{{0}{matched case 1}{.50}{matched case 2}}[matched none]\par

\bigskip% 
This test allows for case where numerically equivalent:\par
\smallskip
\IfEqCase{a}{{a}{matched case 1}{b}{matched case 2}}[matched none]\par
\IfEqCase{b}{{a}{matched case 1}{b}{matched case 2}}[matched none]\par
\IfEqCase{c}{{a}{matched case 1}{b}{matched case 2}}[matched none]\par
\IfEqCase{+3}{{3}{matched case 1}{5}{matched case 2}}[matched none]\par
\IfEqCase{0.5}{{0}{matched case 1}{.50}{matched case 2}}[matched none]\par


\newcommand*{\StrEqEither}[5]{% {string}{target1}{target2}{code for match}{code for no match}
    \IfEqCase{#1}{{#2}{#4}{#3}{#4}}[#5]
}%

\bigskip
This is test using a macro (allows for numerically equivalent):\par
\smallskip
\StrEqEither{a}{a}{b}{matched}{no match}\par
\StrEqEither{b}{a}{b}{matched}{no match}\par
\StrEqEither{c}{a}{b}{matched}{no match}\par
\StrEqEither{+3}{3}{5}{matched}{no match}\par
\StrEqEither{0.5}{0}{.50}{matched}{no match}\par
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the long example. I'll definitely look into xstring.