# newcommand conditionals

Tags: macros, conditionals

I am looking to create a command that adjusts my page layout, here is a sample:

```
\newcommand{\margin}{
\pdfpageheight 297mm
\pdfpagewidth 210mm
\pagebreak
\newgeometry{lmargin=31.5mm, rmargin=31.5mm, includemp, marginparsep=5mm, marginparwidth=52mm}
\setlength{\headwidth}{147mm}}
```

It basically just adjusts the margins to have a 52mm margin on the right hand side, and then I have other layouts too, which I all call with different commands, such as `\margin`, `\nomargin`, `\marginlandscape`, and this brings me to my problem.

Ideally, I would want to only have to use one command, such as

```
\mypagestyle{margin}
\mypagestyle{nomarginlandscape}
```

but I have no idea how to create such a command, I've tried to do it myself and I've looked all over the place, but can find no answers. So, how do I code a `newcommand` that would give me the desired results?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the same mechanism as used for `\pagestyle` (using its original simpler definition without error checking here)

```
\def\mypagestyle#1{\csname myps#1\endcsname}
```

then just define `\mypsmargin` `\mypsnomarginlandscape` to do whatever ever you want and then you can use the syntax

```
\mypagestyle{nomarginlandscape}
```

to call the internal command `\mypsnomarginlandscape`

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand, sorry, I'm new to Tex. Where would I define nomargin, etc? And then how would I add a new definition, of say nomarginlandscape?

Comment: Just change the definition in your question from `\newcommand{\margin}{` to `\newcommand{\mypsmargin}{`  then `\mypagestyle{margin}` will work. Add similar definitions at the same place

Answer (score 2):

This might be overkill, but I normally use [the `xstring` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xstring/) for these sort of thing:

### Further Enhancements:

- This only tests for `margin` but this could easily be extended to support multiple values. If there is just two cases then simply add and another `\IfStrEq`, but for more than two options I would recommend using the `IfStrEqCase` See for instance
  [Checking if a macro expands to one of two given strings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30445/checking-if-a-macro-expands-to-one-of-two-given-strings/).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\mypagestyle}[1]{%
    \IfStrEq{#1}{margin}{%
       Setting "#1": % Adjust settings here
       \newgeometry{lmargin=31.5mm, rmargin=31.5mm, includemp, marginparsep=5mm, marginparwidth=52mm}
    }{%
       Setting "#1": % Adjust settings here
       \newgeometry{lmargin=31.5mm, rmargin=31.5mm, includemp, marginparsep=5mm, marginparwidth=52mm}    }%
}%

\begin{document}
\mypagestyle{margin}

\mypagestyle{nomarginlandscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That looks good, but do you know of a way where I do not need any extra packages? Thanks for the prompt response though.